# js error: while trying to display graph using chart.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I am trying to display a graph on my webpage using chart.js. The code for the chart.js is working fine when I check it in jsfiddle with test data. But when I put it on my webpage, it starts showing errors. There is some problem the way I am trying to use this code on my webpage.

I tried searching the stackoverflow forum to solve the issue the error doesn't go. How can I remove these errors?

Here are the errors:

```
Chart.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

**JS Code**

```
 var Device_Data;
   var temperature, meas_value;


   function dspChrt3(Device_Data) { 
        //console.log(Device_Data);

        var time_Array = [];
        var meas_value_Array = [];

       for(var i=0; i<Device_Data.length; i++) {
            time_Array.push(Device_Data[i].date_time);
            meas_value_Array.push(Device_Data[i].meas_value);
            }

        //console.log(Device_Data[0].date_time);
        //console.log(Device_Data[1].meas_value);
        date_time = Device_Data[0].date_time;
        meas_value = Device_Data[1].meas_value;
        time_Array.shift();
        time_Array.push(date_time);
        meas_value_Array.shift();
        meas_value_Array.push(meas_value);

        console.log(time_Array);
        console.log(meas_value_Array);

        var ctx = document.getElementById ('myChart11').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels: time_Array,
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: meas_value_Array,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
        }]
        },

            options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                        unit: 'minute',
                        displayFormats: {
                            'minute': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                            'hour': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
                        }
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        source: 'data'
                    }
                }]                    
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

**HTML/PHP Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

  <title>Chart.JS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="scripts/chart3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

   <Div>
   <canvas id="myChart11"></canvas>
   </Div>

<?php
    require("Connection.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select date_time, meas_value FROM soil_measurements order by date_time desc limit 12");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $WData = $stmt->fetchAll();


    ?>

    <script>
      var WData = <?php print_r(json_encode($WData));?>;
      //console.log(WData);
      //console.dir(WData);
      dspChrt3(WData);
    </script>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var WData = <?php print_r(json_encode($WData));?>;`  Not sure if it's your only problem, but you definitely want to remove the `print_r()` call there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit so I may follow your guideline.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to be any more clear.

Comment: If you mean assignment operator can work without print_r;       
var WData = <?php json_encode($WData);?>
but then there is no data is shown in WData by console.log(WData), rather it prints 'undefined' while with print_r, the array values are printed.

Comment: graph rendering code within dspChrt3() was required to be put within $(document).ready(function() {}); because it was called before the page was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the docs for print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php): "Prints human-readable information about a variable".  Human-readable information is rarely useful to a computer.

Instead, you want the data in a format that can easily be parsed by your program.  In the case of chart.js, that format would be JSON.  You're already JSON-encoding the data, you just need to stop wrapping it in the extra formatting that comes along with `print_r()`.  Instead, simply just output the data with `echo`.

`var WData = <?php echo json_encode($WData);?>;`

Comment: I used echo too while trying diff solutions, but it didn't resolve the problem.  Same error keep raising. What I search more now on SO, with someone getting kind of same error while using chart.js, the problem lies may be in populating chart.js elements. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572791/chart-js-cannot-read-property